# Drupal webform file upload not saving to database

Tags: drupal, file-upload

I'm writing a custom Drupal module for a mobile service.  That module acts like a web form, but I'm having a problem when uploading a file.  All values are inserted into the database successfully except for the file.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information.  For example, are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm using webform_submission_insert($node, $submission);  in my custom module, it saves all submitted data but the uploaded files, the $data object holds the values of the fields to save into the database with their corresponding cid but what about a field of type file, should I use a string and use drupal_move_uploaded_file check the below code
[code]
 move_uploaded_file('X','Y')
$data = array(
    1 => array('value' => array($_POST['name'])),
    2 => array('value' => array(NAME_OF_UPLOADED_FILE)),
  );
 webform_submission_insert($node, $submission);
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

I think the function "_webform_client_form_submit_process" is not calling "_webform_submit_file". You can try following solution

```
 1. Try using updating your webform module with the latest release.
 2. Try removing your file upload field from fieldset, if its in any.
 3. Check the temp and destination directory permission.
```

Comment: I've almost went over the code of the webform module and I solved it now, you have to use file_save and get the $file->fid and pass it to the data object of the submissions object, then call webform_submission_insert and get the $sid and pass it to file_usage_add, this got my module working.

Answer (score 0):

I've almost went over the code of the webform module and I solved it now, you have to use file_save and get the $file->fid and pass it to the data object of the submissions object, then call webform_submission_insert and get the $sid and pass it to file_usage_add, this got my module working